# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

When i make migration "Add-migration" in ASP.NET Core 2.1. I get the error could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0 How can  i fix this?
Also, i tried to remove the VS2019 and all its components, but that didn't help.
I'm using EntityFrameworkCore.

[image: Dependencies]

[image: CSPROJ]

[image: The Error]

Comment: Does your project build?
And different version in question title and description (4.0.0.0 vs 1.0.61025.0)

Comment: Check that you have System.Web.Extensions under references and the version is correct. Also, check in the web.config file that you have the correct version. Sometimes you may have a different version in web.config and under references.

Comment: @moi_meme i'm sorry my bad, error v4.0.0.0. Yes, my project is being successfully built

Comment: Share us your csproj content. Do you develop with EF or EF Core? How did you create your project? I checked my asp.net core 2.1, there is no reference for `System.Web.Extensions`? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: There should not be `System.Web` *anything* in an ASP.NET Core project. Whatever reference you've added that includes that, needs to be removed.

Comment: It's also odd that you have no EF Core reference, either. How are you even building anything you could migrate against without that. Something's hinky.

Answer (score 0):

my .dll was corrupt. this saved me:

https://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/microsoft/windows/system-web-extensions-dll/#otherknown

Found have to manually place in bin after 1st build, then it remembers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).